# How to get the IP-Address in RTP

Tags: vxworks

How is it possible to get the IP-Address in RTP (real time process) from the system on VxWorks7?
Because ifAddrGet() is not working for RTP.

Answer (score 0):

Use ioctl to get the IP-Address and other information:

```
#include <ioLib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <socklib.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <ipcom_sock.h>



struct sockaddr_in * addrp;
struct ifreq ifr;
int sock;
char ipStr[IP_INET_ADDRSTRLEN]

memset((void *)&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));

strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "gei0");

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sock == ERROR)
    return ERROR;

if(ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) != ERROR)
{
    addrp = (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr; 
    ipcom_inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addrp->sin_addr.s_addr, ipStr,  
        IP_INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
}
else
    return ERROR;

printf("IP: %s", ipStr);

close(sock);

return OK
```